# Change dynamically enum values in a src/java file on Grails

Tags: grails

I have an enum file located on src/java in a Grails project.

This enum has it values defined on the code, can i change this values dynamically?

```
public enum Status
{
    value_one, value_two, value_three;

    public String getOtherString()
    {
        switch (this)
        {
        case value_one:
            return "value one";
        case value_two:
            return "value two";
        case value_three:
            return "value three";
        default:
            return "problem";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        switch (this)
        {
        case value_one:
            return "VALUE 1";
        case value_two:
            return "VALUE 2";
        case value_three:
            return "VALUE 3";
        default:
            return "problem happens";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want to change? add/remove a new enum? change enum name? change response of toString()? change response of getOtherString()?

Comment: I want to change the string responses with something on database, like this:

`case value_one:
            return MyDomain.getValueOne();`

In this way i have a domain called MyDomain which have some atributes that can be changed on database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way using a service.

I convert the enum in a .groovy file and used service methods to return the values.

All works!

Answer (score 2):

You can extend with [metaClass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3525-MetaClasses), before usage. For example by adding into `BootStrap.init()`:

```
Status.metaClass.getValueOne = {
   Status val = delegate
   switch (val) {
        case Status.value_one:
        // read from database
   }
}
```